# Unable to install Rstudio due libclang-dev problem

Tags: package-management, updates, dependencies, clang, rstudio

I am new to ubuntu, and have been trying to install the new version of Rstudio, which should normally work. But it somehow broke today.

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> This package is not able to be installed
> Cannot install 'libclang-dev'`

I understand that it seems to be an error with libclang-dev package itself. Other forums have recommended reverting libc6 library to the normal version:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6:i386=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

But I still get this error:

> E: Version '2.31-0ubuntu9.2' for 'libc6' was not found
> E: Version '2.31-0ubuntu9.2' for 'libc6:i386' was not found

Finally I have tried to install aptitude but I don't think the package exist anymore.

> Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It appears as if rstudio is using outdated libraries not anymore shipped with U 22.04. This should be fixed by the developers. In principle, you could compile the source, but that may prove too challenging.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for getting back to me. Perhaps, I can see if there's a way to compile from source from their website.